# How to read input to a C++ program in reverse order?

Tags: c++, istream

Suppose I give input to a C++ program as follows:

`1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15`

C++ code:

```
int n;
for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
{
    std::cin >> n;
    // use the value of n to make changes
}
```

In the above code I can read the input sequentially,
 i.e. `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15`.

Is there any way to read input directly (without using extra memory in C++ program) from the input stream in the following order:

`5 4 3 2 1 10 9 8 7 6 15 14 13 12 11`

First five digits in reverse order `5 4 3 2 1`, next five digits in reverse order `10 9 8 7 6`, ...

Comment: Does it need to be read in this way, or can it be read in then re-ordered?

Comment: Swimming against the stream.....

Comment: Sounds like you want to put them in an array (`std::vector`), then sort the array using a custom sort function (with `std::stort`)

Comment: Probably this is [the XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? You could just read as is, and re-order it later.

Comment: There is no way to read values from `std::cin` in different order than they are provided as input.   Read five values, sort them, output them.    Repeat twice.   There is a need for memory for something (e.g. an array, object or container) to hold the five values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*No*.

You need to read the data as they flow into the input stream.

In your program then, you can re-order them in any way you like.

Comment: There could be a way to read every 5 numbers in reversed order. Keyboard buffer can help.

Comment: That's not what the OP want, I think.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, the best way to do this is to read them in the order they are given and sort them afterwards.

```
// vector to hold the values
std::vector<int> values;
values.reserve(15); // reserve for better performance

int n;
for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
{
    std::cin >> n;
    values.push_back(n); // add value to back of vector
}

// sort the vector
std::sort(values.begin(), values.end());

// use the values in ascending order...
for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    std::cout << values[i];    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible ,but it increase the running time complexity of the code .

First you can make the outer loop for how many series it insert , in the above test case its 3.

Secondly you can make a inner loop which adds the number .

I am not sure the code is running but the logic helps you .

I am implementing the psuedo code using stack !

```
int n=5;
for(int count = 1 ; count <= 3 ;count++)
{
   for(int i=n ; i > n-5 ; i++)
    {
      push_on_stack(i);
    }
 n=n+5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your taking input in some functionality that reorders the values for you. You might be able to do so outside the program, i.e., pipe the input stream through another program that reorders the values. Then your code might already work as you have it now.

Or you do this wrapping in your program. For example using a custom stream-like class that buffers the values in between.

There's no way to get this done without using extra memory to buffer the values you don't yet need.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>

struct reader {
    std::stack<int> data;
    reader& operator>>(int & i) {
        if (data.empty()) {
            while (data.size() < 5) {
                data.push(0);
                std::cin >> data.top();
            }
        }
        i = data.top();
        data.pop();
        return *this;
    }
    explicit operator bool() const { return bool(std::cin); }
};

int main () {
    reader r;
    int i;
    while (r >> i) {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Example output:

```
$ g++ tt.cc -std=c++11 && echo "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10" | ./a.out
5
4
3
2
1
10
9
8
7
6
```

---

A more straight forward approach would probably be something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main () {
    std::vector<int> buffer;
    for (int i; std::cin >> i; ) {
        buffer.push_back(i);
        if (buffer.size() == 5) {
            // do something with buffer
            //std::vector<int> reversed(buffer.rbegin(), buffer.rend());
            while (!buffer.empty()) {
                std::cout << buffer.back() << "\n";
                buffer.pop_back();
            }
        }
    }
}
```